Selenium Python - Get video codec from multiple pages
I want to scan my blog posts and check whether all videos are of the same codec, how to achieve this with Python on Selenium?
What I've tried:
from selenium import webdriver
  
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
video = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "video")


Inside of HTML you will (at most) find the content-type which can lead you to the type of container format used. But the actual codec of the video stream inside the container will not be there. You have to grab the stream and analyze it to get this information.
